# Simular área de atuação dos pontos em matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Preciso criar um gráfico onde, dada as coordenadas dos pontos, cria-se um circulo de raio x em volta desses pontos. Simulando a área de atuação.

Possuo o seguinte script:

```
================================
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

    x = [10, 15, 24, 34]
    y = [10, 42, 27, 14]
    x0 = 10
    y0 = 10
    r0 = 2
    plt.plot(x, y, '.')
    circle = plt.Circle((x0, y0), r0, color='r', fill=False)
    plt.gca().add_artist(circle)
    plt.axis([0, 50, 0, 50])
    plt.show()
================================
```

Que me gera a seguinte imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém não consigo fazer que todos os pontos tenham seus respectivos círculos em volta.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de construir o circulo sobre um ponto diretamente:

```
x0 = 10
y0 = 10

circle = plt.Circle((x0, y0), r0, color='r', fill=False)
plt.gca().add_artist(circle)
```

Deve faze-lo para todos eles percorrendo a lista de `x` e `y` que tem. Para simplificar isso pode utilizar a função [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) que lhe permite juntar/mesclar dois iteráveis, que no seu caso irá dar `x,y` para cada ponto.

Logo bastaria trocar o código que mencionei acima por:

```
for xi,yi in zip(x,y):
    circle = plt.Circle((xi, yi), r0, color='r', fill=False)
    plt.gca().add_artist(circle)
```

Veja o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código completo para referência:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [10, 15, 24, 34]
y = [10, 42, 27, 14]
r0 = 2
plt.plot(x, y, '.')

for xi,yi in zip(x,y):
    circle = plt.Circle((xi, yi), r0, color='r', fill=False)
    plt.gca().add_artist(circle)

plt.axis([0, 50, 0, 50])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda e explicação.

Comment: @Danilo De nada. Estamos cá para ajudar.